# Android ImageView not displayed and is null

Tags: listview, android-studio, layout-inflater

An ImageView inside a ListView item is not being displayed, however if I just replace ImageView with Button or something it's displayed fine.

**Layout file of the list item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Looked fine in Android Studio:
[image: Android Studio screenshot]

While it's not displayed at runtime:
[image: Runtime screenshot]

Replace "ImageView" by "Button" and run:
[image]

Code that inflate this layout:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View root = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.entry_pickblock_list, viewGroup, false);
        Block blk = getItem(i);
        TextView tv = root.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText(blk.locale_name);
        tv = root.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        tv.setText(getString(R.string.pickblock_entry_detail, blk.id, blk.name));
        ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.image);//iv is null.
        //iv.setImageDrawable(BlockIcons.get(blk.id));
        return root;
    }
```

Yes the ImageView is empty but it should have a border box shown by my debug tool. And more importantly, findViewById returns `null` for the ImageView but returns a **valid** Button reference when it's replaced by a Button.

That's to say, only **ImageViews** are removed in **this** ListView.
ImageViews in other lists are displayed and have border box shown even they're empty; Things else are shown in this ListView with same properties set.

I didn't write code to remove them, and I'm not able to do so at all since I can't even get it from view tree. I don't have Adblock or other Xposed modules installed that manipulates views. Vendor of my system or phone seems not doing so. So who did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
iv = findViewById(R.id.image);//iv is null
```

Shouldn't it be

```
iv = root.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Comment: I have no idea about that, unfortunately.